# Google Kickstart 2020 round D- Record Breaker Question

Tags: c++

is my solution is working Fine for all test cases.
this is google kickstart 2020 round d question.
for 4 test cases my output is correct.
Time Complexity is also O(n).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n+1];
    a[n]  = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    int max = 0;
    int ans = 0;
    if(a[1] < a[max]){
        ans = 1;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if(a[i] > a[max]){
            if(a[i] > a[i+1]){
                max = i;
                ans++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[n+1];` is a *Variable-Length Array*. It is not in the standard C++. You should consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: apart from this, any other issue.

Comment: For working code that can use some improvements http://codereview.stackexchange.com is the right place to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be:

[Record Breaker - Kick Start](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff08/0000000000387171)

Your code is wrong because it outputs `1` for input

```
3
1 2 2
```

while the answer should be `0`.

- The first day is not record breaking because it is not the last day and the number is not strictly larger than one on the following day.
- The second day is not record breaking because it is not the last day and the number is not strictly larger than one on the following day.
- The third day is not record breaking because the number is not strictly larger than one on the second day.

What is wrong is that you are updating the maximum value only if the number on a day is larger than the next day.